# php echo data from certain id

Tags: php, row, echo

EDIT: I'm sorry I was unclear, I try to explain it right this time.

I have this data in a database table called tMenu:

**id  page_nl text**
1   index_1 index1_text
2   index_2 index2_text
3   index_3 index3_text

These are 3 pages on my website called (in this case) index_1, index_2 and index_3. I have programmed it is such a way that each page shows there index1_text.

What I want now is to show page_nl in a menu. The code I have now is:

```
$qh = mysql_query('SELECT id, page_nl FROM tMenu ORDER BY id');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($qh);
$id = 'id';

<a href="index_1.php"><? echo $row['page_nl']; $id=="1" ;?></a>
<a href="index_2.php"><? echo $row['page_nl']; $id=="2" ;?></a>
<a href="index_3.php"><? echo $row['page_nl'];?></a>
```

In the way it is now it shows only page_nl from id 1, but I want that the next link shows page_nl from id 2. I hope my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `foreach($var as $key =>$value)` loop

Comment: Which variables do I need to put instead of $var, $key and $value? When using the code from above

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear - are you asking for something like this

```
$sql = "select * from yourtable where id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//I am assuming there are more than 1 rows for ID 1
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo $row['page_nl'];
}
```

OR ============================

```
$sql = "select * from yourtable"; //Select All
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    if($row['id'] == 1) 
    {
         echo $row['page_nl'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you mean database table, you need a routine to connect to the database then fetch the info:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "databasename"); // database name

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name"; // put table name here
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* numeric array */

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["id"], $row["page_nl"]);


/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```